# Crash in WebCore when opening a Facebook Dialog

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, webkit, crash

I am using Facebook SDK to open a dialog that user can use to post a comment on another user's Facebook timeline. Sometimes the application crashes at the exact point of opening the Facebook dialog. The snippet of the crashlog:

```
Date/Time:       2012-03-19 16:33:00.053 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000008
Crashed Thread:  2

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   WebCore                         0x3248578a WebCore::FrameLoader::interruptionForPolicyChangeError(WebCore::ResourceRequest const&) const + 2
1   WebCore                         0x326f1e98 WebCore::MainResourceLoader::stopLoadingForPolicyChange() + 20
2   WebCore                         0x322f9200 WebCore::MainResourceLoader::callContinueAfterNavigationPolicy(void*, WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>, bool) + 8
3   WebCore                         0x321d07ec WebCore::PolicyCallback::cancel() + 48
4   WebCore                         0x321d0326 WebCore::PolicyChecker::stopCheck() + 38
5   WebCore                         0x321d219a WebCore::FrameLoader::stopAllLoaders(WebCore::ClearProvisionalItemPolicy) + 34
6   WebCore                         0x322f0986 WebCore::FrameLoader::detachFromParent() + 90
7   WebKit                          0x31b0ad0c __-[WebView(WebPrivate) _close]_block_invoke_7 + 364
8   WebCore                         0x3215a502 HandleRunSource + 358
9   CoreFoundation                  0x30e9dacc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30e9d32e __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 358
11  CoreFoundation                  0x30e9c03e __CFRunLoopRun + 646
12  CoreFoundation                  0x30e1f49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
13  CoreFoundation                  0x30e1f366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
14  WebCore                         0x321ae0f0 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x377bf72e _pthread_start + 314
16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x377bf5e8 thread_start + 0
```

Any idea what may be causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: Seems not enough feedback are available for WebCore crash. How do you fix it finally?

Comment: I didn't. It could be a memory issue. I disabled handling viewDidUnload because we were not doing it properly and this particular error kind of stopped occurring as often. It could be something else though.